# Intercept File read to allow only classes from specific packages to read a specific file

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have a usecase where I want to allow only classes from certain packages to read from a directory of files. This is achievable through grant policy in SecurityManager using a file like

```
grant codeBase "file:/path/to/application.jar" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/path/to/directory/*", "read,write";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.allowed.package";
};
```

but given that `SecurityManager` is deprecated, I was thinking if there is a way to achieve the same using byte-buddy.

**Edit 1**

I wrote this FileInterceptor to intercept all file reads. I am trying to do it at a BufferedReader level

```
public class FileInterceptor {

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside premain");
        File temp = Files.createTempDirectory("tmp").toFile();
        Map<TypeDescription.ForLoadedType, byte[]> injectTypes = new HashMap<>();
        injectTypes.put(new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(BufferedReaderAdvice.class),
            ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(BufferedReaderAdvice.class));
        ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.of(temp,
            ClassInjector.UsingInstrumentation.Target.BOOTSTRAP, instrumentation).inject(injectTypes);

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .ignore(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy."))
            .with(new AgentBuilder.InjectionStrategy.UsingInstrumentation(instrumentation, temp))
            .type(ElementMatchers.named("java.io.BufferedReader"))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module, protectionDomain) ->
                builder.visit(Advice.to(BufferedReaderAdvice.class).on(
                    ElementMatchers.isConstructor().and(ElementMatchers.any()
                    )))) // Intercept calls to BufferedReader(InputStreamReader)
            .installOn(instrumentation);
    }

    public static class BufferedReaderAdvice {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter()
        
        public static void enter(@Advice.This BufferedReader bufferedReader, @Advice.Argument(0) Reader fileReader) {
            String path = new File(((InputStreamReader) fileReader).getEncoding()).getAbsolutePath(); // Get the absolute path of the file
            System.out.println("Inside enter");
            if (path.startsWith("/path/") &&
                !bufferedReader.getClass().getPackage().getName().startsWith("com.whitelist")) {
                // Deny access for files in the path of interest but not being accessed by a package of interest
                throw new SecurityException("Access denied");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to intercept calls via `Files.readAllLines(path)` in another project which uses the above as a javaagent. What I see happening is that the `Inside premain` gets invoked but the enter method doesn't get invoked. What am I missing in this case?

**Edit 2**

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside premain");
        new AgentBuilder.Default().disableClassFormatChanges().with(RETRANSFORMATION).ignore(none())
            .type(ElementMatchers.named("java.io.BufferedReader"))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module, protectionDomain) ->
                builder.visit(Advice.to(BufferedReaderAdvice.class).on(isConstructor())))
            .installOn(instrumentation);
```

```
public static class BufferedReaderAdvice {
        @Advice.OnMethodEnter()
        public static void enter(@Advice.Origin Constructor constructor, @Advice.AllArguments Object[] params) {
            System.out.println("Inside enter");
            System.out.println("enter-------" + constructor.getDeclaringClass());
            String callingPackage = constructor.getDeclaringClass().getPackage().getName();
            InputStreamReader streamReader = (InputStreamReader) params[0];
            String path = new File(streamReader.getEncoding()).getAbsolutePath(); // Get the absolute path of the file
            System.out.println("callingPackage-->" + callingPackage);
            System.out.println("path-->" + path);
            for (Object param:params) {
                System.out.println(param);
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling code:

```
public void readFile(String filePath) {
        System.out.println("Class:"+getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
            System.out.println(lines);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you merely want to prevent _accidental_ / unintentional access to other dirs, sure, you can use bytebuddy to rewrite all calls to `Files.*` and `new FileOutputStream` and the like. You'll need to go hunt down every call that is relevant. And redirect it to code that checks if the path is fine and if not, throws something. __But if you are relying on this for security, do not do that__. Don't run code you don't trust except in an OS-level sandbox (So, boot a separate JVM inside a sandboxed container). This advice _also_ applies to SecurityManager - that's not secure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah it's slightly tricky at this point. OS-level sandboxing while ideal is hard for the way our application is setup. And it's a multi tenant application and it's sort of inevitable to load these untrusted third party libraries.

Comment: A very quick way to get around a BB script that scans for any file-relevant methods is to just make your calls with reflection. `Class.forName("java.io.FileOutputStrea#".replace("#", "m"));`, go from there. You can attempt to batch `FileOutputStream` _itself_ somehow, but modern JVMs don't like it if you try that.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the original question to add a code fragment which I came up with to intercept the file read calls using byte-buddy. It doesn't seem to be working though. Any. help would be appreciated.

Comment: BufferedReader? That's.. unrelated to files entirely. The reason it probably doesn't work is that core classes are _already loaded_ and cannot be modified.

Comment: As I said, I am using `Files.readAllLines(path)` which creates a BufferedReader object and that's the reason I decided to go ahead with that approach. Also, I am using a temp directory because BufferedReader is loaded using bootstrap classloader.

Comment: `new FileInputStream` does not use BufferedReader at all. It feels like you have no idea what you are doing, which, you know, we've all been there and this is a very complex thing you're trying to solve. Given that it's a security thing, you _can't_ just try stuff. You have no idea if what you wrote actually 'works'. I think you should rely on a much simpler: Do not upgrade JDK, _or_, start trusting or manually reviewing plugins.

Comment: Well I am not an expert in this :) but I did get it working. Check the edit 2. The main thing needed was the change in `premain` method to not `ignore` any types. By default, byte-buddy ignores java classes loaded by bootstrap classloaders. This link helped: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1360 I see the control flow entering the `enter` method when I invoke the `Files.readAllLines` method.

Comment: Also, when I check the implementation of `readAllLines`, I see a BufferedReader object is created.. I am not using `FileInputStream` yes

Comment: Trust me, you haven't made it impossible to open files you don't want apps to open, not by a long shot.

Comment: Yes I am aware. This is Just one of the read paths and there could be multiple ways of opening files. For now, I won’t be proceeding with this way either. Thanks for your help on this !